# How to focus on a form input text field on page load using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

This is probably very simple, but could somebody tell me how to get the cursor blinking on a text box on page load?

Answer (score 445, accepted):

Set focus on the first text field:

```
 $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
```

This also does the first text field, but you can change the [0] to another index:

```
$('input[@type="text"]')[0].focus();
```

Or, you can use the ID:

```
$("#someTextBox").focus();
```

Comment: If using a dialog please see this answer if the above is not working http://stackoverflow.com/a/20629541/966609

Comment: `$('input[type="text"]').get(0).focus();`   ...worked for me

Comment: `.focus()` was depricated in 3.3, for newer versions use `.trigger('focus');`

Answer (score 112):

You can use [HTML5 `autofocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) for this. You don't need jQuery or other JavaScript.

```
<input type="text" name="some_field" autofocus>
```

Note this will not work on IE9 and lower.

Comment: autofocus does not work in IE11 either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068302/autofocus-attribute-on-input-field-not-working-in-ie-11

Comment: This works for my scenario but the selected answer did not for some reason.

Comment: This is great and also shorter, even if a single letter `id` was used! :P

Answer (score 30):

Sure:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#myTextBox").focus();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myTextBox">
</body>
```

Comment: I recommend to bring the script after html element.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour script is within the dom ready wrapper so it doesn't matter that it's before the html element, but it shouldn't be in head anyway.

Answer (score 22):

Why is everybody using jQuery for something simple as this.

```
<body OnLoad="document.myform.mytextfield.focus();">
```

Comment: Because the question is tagged as jQuery.

Answer (score 21):

Think about your user interface before you do this. I assume (though none of the answers has said so) that you'll be doing this when the document loads using jQuery's `ready()` function. If a user has already focussed on a different element before the document has loaded (which is perfectly possible) then it's extremely irritating for them to have the focus stolen away.

You could check for this by adding `onfocus` attributes in each of your `<input>` elements to record whether the user has already focussed on a form field and then not stealing the focus if they have:

```
var anyFieldReceivedFocus = false;

function fieldReceivedFocus() {
    anyFieldReceivedFocus = true;
}

function focusFirstField() {
    if (!anyFieldReceivedFocus) {
        // Do jQuery focus stuff
    }
}


<input type="text" onfocus="fieldReceivedFocus()" name="one">
<input type="text" onfocus="fieldReceivedFocus()" name="two">
```

Comment: Your perspective is not only technically correct, but your consideration for the best UX possible is exquisite. Bravo!

Answer (score 13):

HTML:

```
  <input id="search" size="10" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#search").focus();
```

Comment: if using html5, just add `autofocus` attribute to the input element?

Comment: How is that attribute used, and will it become the focused element as soon as its parent form appears?

Answer (score 11):

Sorry for bumping an old question. I found this via google.

Its also worth noting that its possible to use more than one selector, thus you can target any form element, and not just one specific type.

eg.

```
$('#myform input,#myform textarea').first().focus();
```

This will focus the first input or textarea it finds, and of course you can add other selectors into the mix as well.  Handy if you can't be certain of a specific element type being first, or if you want something a bit general/reusable.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I prefer to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fieldID").focus(); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's bad way to do things, to focus on an <input> on document load, just use the `autofocus` attribute provided by HTML5

Answer (score 3):

place after input

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.formname.inputname.focus();</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$("#search").focus();`

You can also use HTML5 element `<autofocus>`

Answer (score 2):

The line `$('#myTextBox').focus()` alone won't put the cursor in the text box, instead use:

```
$('#myTextBox:text:visible:first').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simple and easiest way to achieve this

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    $('.form-group input[type="text"]').attr('autofocus', 'true');
});
```