# Make an input secret get focus when page is ready

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I´m trying to do that with DOM:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                document.getElementById('frmTotem:undCGC').focus();
            });
        </script>
```

Where "undCGC" is an input secret from richfaces -> h:inputSecret.

But focus() or select() functions do not work properly. Any cue will be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: we had this question (and answer) in the past... please checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591910/how-to-focus-on-a-form-input-text-field-on-page-load-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the following?

```
document.getElementById('undCGC').focus();
```

Comment: Thanks but didn´t work! My ID is the same informed, but the code does not focus the element.

Comment: Then it is probable that the presence of the DOM still does not mean that everything is rendered. See http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/12/richfaces-built-in-client-functions/, and maybe http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks Joop, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ito ,

I also face same issue in past,

I just say its your some property issue for `<h:inputSecret>` tag .

checkout this link  [http://myfaces.apache.org](http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/tagdoc/h_inputSecret.html) , here you can see when focus works or not for inputSecret. search "focus" in page and you will get all condition where its work or not.

Let me know if not works,next time provide your code